# Find $x\in G$ such that $K=xHx^{-1}$ iff there exists a bijection $\psi : G/H \to G/K$ such that $\psi(gH)=g\psi(H)$ for all $g\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be $2$ subgroups of $G$. Show that there exists $x\in G$ such that $K=xHx^{-1}$ if and only if there exists a bijection $\psi : G/H \to G/K$ such that $\psi(gH)=g\psi(H)$ for all $g \in G$.

How to do this question? If $K=xHx^{-1}$ with $x \in Z(G)$ then defining $\psi(H)=xHx^{-1}$ has the property but then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1**

> Suppose first there is such a $\psi$.

**Hint 2**

> Let $y \in H$ be such that $\psi(H) = x K$. Then $\psi( g H ) = g \psi(H) = g y K$.

**Hint 3**

> Since $\psi$ is a bijection, you have in particular $g H = H$ iff $g y K = y K$, that is $g \in H$ iff $y^{-1} g y \in K$, that is, $K = y^{-1} H y$.

**Hint 4**

> Now the converse should be clear

Comment: So for the converse: Suppose there exist $x$ such that $K=xHx^{-1}$. Define $\psi(H)=xK$, and $\psi(gH)=gxK$. And then check that it is bijective. Have I gotten it right?

Comment: @eatfood, two comments. Given the first part you can skip the particular case $\psi(H) = x K$, and define directly $\psi(g H) = g x K$. And then, you should first check that this map is well-defined, but you will see that this comes for free in a sense.

Comment: Ok I get what you mean. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please note that I have corrected a misprint, which affects your answer. The map should be $\psi(g H) = g x^{-1} K$.